# Document comparison using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, compare, comparison, pdfbox, document

Is there way to compare two PDF files using PDFBox and show the comparison results in a result pdf file.
I think we can do it using PDFTextStripper and then compare the texts but it does not create comparison result in a new pdf. I want to have new PDF created showing comparison result

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is such a library and it even uses PDFBox: [PdfCompare](https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare).
Next time such question should better be asked at the [open source section](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) on stackexchange.